# Html accessing JS file on Jupyter notebook

Tags: javascript, html, web

I am new to web programming and I have the following issue.

So I am trying to set up a small server on Jupyter notebook. The issue right now is when I do

```
<script src="../src/main.js">
```

in my HTML, it cannot find the corresponding JS file. I tried `http://localhost:8888/src/main.js` as the path but this does not work either as it is forbidden.

I am wondering is there any way to work around this?

Thanks

EDIT: the project structure is similar to the following

```
/
  server.py
src/  
  main.js  
templates/  
  main.html
```

`server.py` is a flask application that can render the `main.html`.

Comment: can you please add your project structure

Comment: I just updated the question, thanks!

Comment: can you share the error stack or code you trying to execute because I could not able to replicate the issue in my system

Comment: It is `GET http://localhost:8888/src/main.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)` or simply 404 not found if I do `../src/main.js`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to include the static files in the flask first you need to follow the folder structure

I have attached the link below for your reference [Here](https://exploreflask.com/en/latest/static.html)

and answering your question

move the js file to a static/ subdirectory

```
url_for('static', filename='path/to/file')
```

in your HTML file

you can find more details [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#static-files)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked! It's really hard to navigate through the Flask doc. from scratch...